# Sufficient condition for a function to be affine

Tags: functions, convex-analysis, functional-equations, affine-geometry

If for a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, I can prove for any real $x,y$, that $f(\frac{x+y}{2})=\frac{f(x)}{2}+\frac{f(y)}{2}$, can I say for sure that it is affine, as in of the form $f(x)=ax+b$?

I am referring to the case of equality in Jensen's inequality here, but I'm thinking that maybe it is necessary to prove that $f(tx+(1-t)y)=tf(x)+(1-t)f(y)$ for any $t\in (0,1)$, and that the particular case of $t=1/2$, which I have, isn't sufficient.

Comment: Unless $b=0$ ,the function $f(x)=ax+b$ not linear but _affine_. Please consider correcting this both in the title and in the question.

Comment: I guess this is an issue of convention, where I learn, functions of that form are named linear, but anyhow I specified the form specifically to make this clear.

Comment: BTW this is called [Jensen functional equation](https://www.google.com/search?q=jensen+functional+equation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you have $f(x)$ monotonic over some interval. That is sufficient. Rewrite as $f(x)+f(y)=2f(\frac{x+y}{2})$. Setting $y=0$ gives $2f(\frac{x}{2})=f(x)+f(0)$. Thus $f(x)+f(y)=2f(\frac{x+y}{2})=f(x+y)+f(0)$, so that $g(x)=f(x)-f(0)$ satisfies the Cauchy equation $g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y)$. Thus $g(x)=xg(1) \, \forall x \in \mathbb{Q}$. (I assume you know how to show this?) WLOG take $g(1) \geq 0$, otherwise just use $g'(x)=-g(x)$ in place of $g(x)$ in the following proof.

Since $f(x)$ is monotonic over some interval $I$, $g(x)$ is also monotonic over some interval $I$. Since $g(1) \geq 0$ and $g(x)=xg(1) \, \forall x \in \mathbb{Q}$, $g(x)$ cannot be decreasing, and so must be non-decreasing. Consider $x \in I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, where $x$ is not an endpoint of $I$. Since the rationals are dense in $\mathbb{R}$, $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists p, q \in \mathbb{Q}$ s.t. $x-\epsilon<p<x<q<x+\epsilon$, then considering $\epsilon$ small enough so that $(x-\epsilon), (x+\epsilon) \in I$ (possible since $x$ is not an end point). Thus $g(1)(x-\epsilon) \leq pg(1)=g(p)\leq g(x) \leq g(q)=qg(1) \leq g(1)(x+\epsilon)$, so $g(x)=xg(1) \, \forall x \in I$, except maybe the end points.

Now for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, we can write $x=x'+k$, where $k \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $x' \in I$, $x'$ not an endpoint of $I$. Then $g(x)=g(x')+g(k)=x'g(1)+kg(1)=xg(1)$, so $g(x)=xg(1) \, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, so $f(x)=g(x)+f(0)=x(f(1)-f(0))+f(0) \, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: thank you, but one question. x-ϵ<p -> g(x-ϵ)<= g(p)=p*g(1) obviously, but how did g(x-ϵ) become g(1)*(x-ϵ)? I'm confused since x-ϵ isn't a rational.

Comment: You don't have $g(x-\epsilon)$ becoming $g(1)(x-\epsilon)$. You have $g(1)(x-\epsilon) \leq pg(1)=g(p)\leq g(x) \leq g(q)=qg(1) \leq g(1)(x+\epsilon)$

Comment: oh! i see now, my bad, and again thanks

Answer (score 3):

Having just $t = 1/2$ case is not sufficient. The following is the standard example for "midpoint convex does not imply convex" (assuming axiom of choice):

> Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined as follows. Since $\mathbb{R}$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$ vector space, it admits a Hamel basis. Let $\beta$ be an irrational basis element. Define $f$ to be the "projection to $\beta$", as in for any given $x$, $f(x)$ is the coefficient (a rational number) in front of $\beta$ in the basis expansion of $x$. This function is $\mathbb{Q}$-linear, and hence mid-point linear and mid-point convex. But it is not $\mathbb{R}$-linear or $\mathbb{R}$-convex.

Assuming continuity then your assertion is true. If I remember correctly you can also weaken to assuming $f$ is Lebesgue measurable, but I don't remember the proof off the top of my head.

Comment: Aw, thank you, I was afraid it was so, but I don't have continuity specified and I don't know how to expand to any real t, at most I can make it to any 1/q, with q integer

Comment: Do you have continuity at one single point? Or boundedness on compact intervals? Either of those I think can also be enough. If not then even if you have the full $\mathbb{Q}$ coefficients it is not enough.

Comment: I have that for any arithmetic progression (an) the sequence (f(an)) is an arithmetic progression, but I'm not sure I can prove continuity from that.

Comment: Midpoint convex is equivalent to the Cauchy-like equation $(f(x+y)-f(0))=(f(x)-f(0))+(f(y)-f(0))$. Apart from continuity at a point and boundedness mentioned by @Willie Wong, do you have monotonicity over an interval? It might be better if you provide the context.

Comment: I do have monotonicity. So the full context is that I have a function and for every arithmetic progression, the sequence (f(an)) is also an arithmetic progression, and as x approaches infinity, f(x) approaches infinity. From there I got to the relation specified in my question and from there I can also prove that the function is monotonous. The question is to determine f.

Comment: Then that (monotonicity) is sufficient for you to conclude that $f(x)=ax+b$. Do you require a proof of this?

Comment: Yes, please :) I'm not sure how to use the fact that the function is monotonous with what I've got so far

Comment: Do you know that monotonicty implies continuity except on a countable set?

Comment: I thought monotonicity and surjectivity implied continuity on not-countable sets, for example f(x)=x-5 for x<=0; and x+5 for x>0, which is monotonous though not continuous in 0.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If we suppose $f$ is continuous then we can prove that $f$ is affine by following these steps:

- we prove, for all $b\in\mathbb{R}$,  if $f$ satisfies the given relation, then also for the function $g:x\mapsto f(x)+b$;
- we suppose $f(0)=0$  so we prove that $f$ is odd. We denote $f(1)=a$;
- we prove:
  $$f(x)=ax,\quad \forall x\in \{\frac{m}{2^n}|m\in\mathbb{N}\};$$
- by density and continuity of $f$ we have $f(x)=ax,\quad \forall x\in\mathbb{R}_+$.
  Now, we can conclude.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x)=f(x)-f(0)$

1) $g(0)=0$

2)$g(-x)=-g(x)$

As $g(\frac{x-x}{2})=\frac{1}2(g(x)+g(-x))=0$

3)$g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y)$

As $g(\frac{x}{2})=\frac12g(x)$, So
$g(\dfrac{x+y}{2})=g(\frac {x}{2})+g(\frac {y}{2})$

4) $g(nx)=ng(x) \; n\in\mathbb{N}$

(Prove it by using 3)

5)$g(\frac pqx)=\frac{p}{q} g(x)$

(Using 4)

Then $g(x)=g(1)x \; $ if $x\in \mathbb{Q}$

If f is continuous, we can extend this to real numbers.

Comment: but this isn't necessarily a function of the form f(x)=a*x, I mean the function f(x)=x+1 respects the condition

Comment: Made a mistake, I will edit the answer.